# Split one long gt() table into two or three smaller tables

Tags: r, split, gt

While creating my descriptive table with the gt() package I get a very long table. Is it possible to split such a table in multiple shorter tables?

The table I am using for the code: total1
[image: 1]

I get my long table using gt() like this:

````
test1<-total1%>% dplyr::group_by(a)  %>% gt() %>% 
 fmt_markdown(columns = everything()) %>% tab_header(title = paste("Bilan génétique ",annee,sep=""),
                                    subtitle = paste("Département ",i,sep=""))%>%
 cols_align( align = "center",
   columns = c("Adhérents PHF","Adhérents CL"))%>%
 tab_style(
   style = cell_text(color = "black", weight = "bold"),
   locations = list(
     cells_row_groups(),
     cells_column_labels(everything())
   )
 ) %>% 
 tab_options(
   row_group.border.top.width = px(3),
   row_group.border.top.color = "black",
   row_group.border.bottom.color = "black",
   table.border.top.color = "white",
   heading.border.bottom.color = "black",
   table.border.bottom.color = "white",
   column_labels.border.top.color = "black",
   column_labels.border.bottom.color = "black",
   table_body.border.bottom.color = "black",
   table_body.hlines.color = "white"
 )
gtsave(test1, "test6.pdf", zoom=0.8) ```
````

I would like to just "cut" the table in the middle for example, so that when I pass it to pdf with webshot, it doesn't show this large table in one page (which make it unreadable).

Thank you,

Comment: If you don't mind using `huxtable` rather than `gt`, it has `split_across()` which cuts a table into a list of tables.